# Powershell compare command for 2 folders having corrupt folders

Tags: powershell, compare, get-childitem

I am using the command below to compare 2 paths and I get an error msg. when it gets to a folder that ends with a period in the name ie "Folder123."
When I manually try to open those folders I get an error, so I think they are corrupt.  How can I skip all folders that end with a period or at least ignore the errors so that my processing can finish?

```
Compare (Get-ChildItem -r Y:\Ftp\BFold\Final) (Get-ChildItem -r Y:\Dest\TFold\Temp)
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting that error because it's part of [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions) limitations in Windows. One or severals of the tools you're using are not able to handle this special case.

> Do not end a file or directory name with a space or a period. Although the underlying file system may support such names, the Windows shell and user interface does not. However, it is acceptable to specify a period as the first character of a name. For example, ".temp".

You could either filter the list of folders or using the [`-ErrorAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7.1#-erroraction) to change what happens on an error. Depending on what're you're seeing the error migth already by purely cosmetic.

For Filtering you could use `Where-Object` for example with `-NotMatch ".*\.$"`.